# Power Query - Table.TranformColumns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm trying to add leading zeros into a column in power query call JobCodes. I know I can do this by adding a new column using `Text.Start([JobCodes],5,"0")`, but I don't want to add a new column and go back to remove the column I don't need. I want to be able to do this in one step using `Table.TransformColumns` function. Is this possible?

### Code:

```
Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", each Text.PadStart([JobCodes],5,"0"))
```

### Error:

> Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Function to type List.
>   Details:
>       Value=Function
>       Type=Type

Comment: If your question is resolved, please choose one of the answers to accept so it gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 7):

Your syntax is just a bit off.

I think this is what you want:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"JobCodes", each Text.PadStart(_, 5,"0")}})
```

The error is because it was expecting a list of columns that you want to transform (notice the `{{...}}` above.

---

The easiest wat to get the syntax right is to use the GUI to do a transformation and then just edit the function a bit. For example, you could use Format > Add Prefix which would give you the following step (assuming you choose to prefix `000`).

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"JobCodes", each "000" & _, type text}})
```

Just take out the `"000" & _` and put in the transformation you actually want.

Comment: Thanks!! very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
= Table.ReplaceValue( Source, each  [JobCodes] ,each Text.PadStart(Number.ToText([JobCodes]),5,"0") ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"JobCodes"})
in Replace
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct expresion is:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"JobCodes", each Text.PadStart(Text.From( _), 6, "0"), type text}})
```